# Radio button not working within nested ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a web page with check boxes & radio buttons within nested ng-repeats. When I am clicking the check boxes the underlying view model is getting updated properly, but when I click on the radio buttons, the view model is not getting updated properly. Within a group, when I select an option the selected model property gets updated to true but the other one doesn't change to false.

e.g. when I click on the radio buttons against chicken one by one, all of them becomes true. When I select any one, I want the other ones to become false

My view model is given below.

```
$scope.itemGroups = [{
        "name": 'Non Veg',
            "items": [{
            "selected": false,
                "name": 'Chicken',
                "Portions": [{
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '1 Cup'
            }, {
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '2 Cups'
            }, {
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '3 cups'
            }]
        }, {
            "selected": true,
                "name": 'Egg',
                "Portions": [{
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '1 Cup'
            }, {
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '2 Cups'
            }, {
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '3 cups'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": 'Veggie',
            "items": [{
            "selected": false,
                "name": 'Potato',
                "Portions": [{
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '1 Cup'
            }, {
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '2 Cups'
            }, {
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '3 cups'
            }]
        }, {
            "selected": false,
                "name": 'Tomato',
                "Portions": [{
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '1 Cup'
            }, {
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '2 Cups'
            }, {
                "selected": false,
                    "name": '3 cups'
            }]
        }]
    }];
```

The way I bind to the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="itemGrp in itemGroups">
             <h1>{{itemGrp.name}}</h1>

            <div ng-repeat="item in itemGrp.items">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" />{{item.name}}
                <label ng-repeat="portion in item.Portions">{{portion.name}}
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_{{itemGrp.name}}" ng-model="portion.selected" ng-value="true" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awqv0rb0/16/

Can you please guide me on what can be the issue here? Is there a better way of achieving what I am trying to do here? I need to loop through the JSON and get the values of the selected items.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted here doesn't quite match the fiddle you provided, but your issue is the result of giving each radio button it's own name, and therefore, it's own group.  This allows all radio buttons to essentially function as check boxes and all be set to true instead of the desired behavior of allowing only one.

Instead, you should give all radio buttons under that item the same group name, like:

```
name="{{item.name}}"
```

Your nested ng-repeats should look something like this when you're done:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemGrp.items">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" />{{item.name}}
  <label ng-repeat="portion in item.Portions">{{portion.name}}
    <input type="radio" name="{{item.name}}" ng-model="portion.selected" ng-value="true" />
  </label>
</div>
```

---

**Updated per your Comment**

To update the `selected:true` value of each of your portions when you change one, you'll need a little bit more code. This is a little messy, so it may not be the best solution--but I was able to get it to work.

In addition to the `ng-value="true"` you should also add an `ng-change="toggleRadio(itemGrp,item,portion)"`to your radio buttons.  In your js, you should add the following function:

```
 $scope.toggleRadio = function(itemGrp, item, obj) {
      var indexOfItemGrp = $scope.itemGroups.indexOf(itemGrp);
      var indexOfItem = $scope.itemGroups[indexOfItemGrp].items.indexOf(item);
      var indexOfPortion = $scope.itemGroups[indexOfItemGrp].items[indexOfItem].Portions.indexOf(obj);
        angular.forEach($scope.itemGroups[indexOfItemGrp].items[indexOfItem].Portions, function(value,key)     {
            if(indexOfPortion != key) {
                value.selected = false;
            }
        });
    };
```

Basically, this code will iterate through all of the portion options inside the item inside the itemGroup and update their value to false unless they were the selected option.

You can see a working example in a fork of your original fiddle that I created: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xufd6uaw/).

---

**One More Update**

Have a look at this question: [AngularJS Binding Radio Buttons To Booleans Across Multiple Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724154/angularjs-binding-radio-buttons-to-booleans-across-multiple-objects).  If you can change the model of your json object, this might be a viable solution.  If you can't change the model, manually updating the other values is your cleanest option.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected that. However the main problem which I am facing is that when I click on the radio buttons against chicken one by one, all of them becomes true in the view model. When I select one, I want the other ones to become false. Please check the value in the JSON above.

Comment: Great. I will go with this for now. Wondering if there was a simpler solution with just two-way binding!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial issue. I too, faced it an earlier stages.

If you are looping over a group of items and each item has a set of radio buttons, then all the radio buttons for a given item must have the 'name' attribute value as the item name.

Ex. If the item name is 'Chicken', all it's radio buttons labelled as '1 Cup', '2 Cups', '3 Cups' should have their name='{{item.name}}' i.e. 'Chicken'.

Change Point in your Code:

```
<input type="radio" name="{{item.name}}" ng-model="portion.selected" ng-value="true" />
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshchitlangia/p65frrq7/1/) demo

Comment: Actually, the problem is when you click on 1 Cup it becomes true. Then when you click on 2 cups, it becomes true but 1 Cup also remains true. You can check it in the JSON above.